# What's wrong with this simple jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm targetting the image in the following HTML

```
<h1 class="logo-site-name">
  <span id="logo">
    <a href="http://some.link">
      <img src="http://www.other.com/some.gif">
    </a>
  </span>
</h1>
```

And I'm attempting to replace the image with the following code, but it isn't working. Am I selecting & modifying correctly?

`$('#logo').children('img').attr('src', 'http://www.domain.com/image.gif');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `img` element isn't a child of `logo`, it is a descendant.

You could do

```
$('#logo').find('img:first').attr('src', 'http://www.domain.com/image.gif');
```

The `first` is optional, but if you only have one I like to restrict.

Comment: What about doing $("#logo img").attr("src", "http://www.domain.com/image.gif"); instead of using the find method?

Comment: @Aaron While that will provide the result the difference there is understanding how the underlying selector engine works. Using the object scope and finding within it is generally faster then using a more global selector that will have to be parsed out by the engine and translated into the `find` call anyway. This post might be a little dated but should provide some info, it is worthy to note as well that jQuery has been enhanced in the meantime. http://aahacreative.com/2010/07/19/jquery-fastest-method-find-descendents/

Comment: That's very good to know. Thanks for sharing that. Guess I don't understand the selector engine very well.

Comment: here the img IS a child of #logo! that is how .find works! but there is no need for the .children or .find simply $("#logo img").attr ect would suffice, same as css, and its neat and quick.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#logo a').find('img').attr('src', 'http://www.domain.com/image.gif');
```

this may work..

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#logo img").attr("src","url here");
```

simplest way!!!
dont need the .find.

Simples!!

Answer (score 0):

Children looks for only immediate children (one level only) [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) . Use find

```
$('#logo').find('img').attr('src', 'http://www.domain.com/image.gif');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use context. Usually is cleaner, and you will limit your selection. something like:

```
$('a', '#logo').attr('src', 'http://www.domain.com/image.gif');
```

Comment: this wont work. it will set the source of the a tag and the span, not the image. and because neither a tags or spans have src attributes nothing much will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
$('#logo>a>img').attr('src', 'http://www.domain.com/image.gif');
```

It's simpler and faster...

Comment: that in this case is the same of $('#logo a img') ?

Comment: ^^look above^^ even quicker $("#logo img") dont need the 'a'.

Comment: Well, the way I do selectors is always as accurate as possible, so if you add, ie, a new image inside the #logo div, you wouldn't have to change it...